# Call partial view inside element with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, visual-studio-2013, partial-views

I Have a function called ValidarLogueo, which will return 0 for common users and 1 for administrator users. I'm trying to do somthing like this but it's giving me a **bad compile constant value** error.

```
<input id="Logueo" value="Login" class="btn btn-info btn-block" onclick="javascript:validarLogueo() == 0? @Url.Action('VistaViandasPersonal', 'Menu'): @Url.Action('VistaAdministrador', 'Menu')">
```

I'm now rendering the page in my .js like this, but it's not what i need due to the url keeps in localHost, instead of localHost/Menu

```
 $('body').load(url + '/Menu/VistaViandasPersonal');
```

Is there anything I can do to achive that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, so i ended up putting all my .js code inside a script tag of the .cshtml

    if (parseInt(object.isAdmin) == 0) {
                        
                            url = '@Url.Action("VistaViandasPersonal", "Menu")';
                        } else {
                            url = '@Url.Action("VistaAdministrador", "Menu")';
                     }

And this just worked perfectly, razor was able to parse the action method. I know it's not the best way to do it but I at least could skip the inconvenient. Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to see you completely ignored my advice :) your JS should be in separate JS files so you can a) debug it properly with VS and b) use Typescript or other high level languages.

Comment: Couldn't find a best way. I have to deliver this app next week and I have to resolve other issues i'm having. I'll post again when I find the proper solution to this issue. I know the scripts must be in a separate file. Thx for the help!

Comment: The point being, that once the JS is in separate files, you *cannot use Razor injection* into scripts and need to inject values into the layout pages instead etc. If you can provide more details, I will be happy to clarify my suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the generated code manually, you will see you are trying to inject *string constants*, but have not included the delimiting quotes. Add single quotes around the `@Url.Action` calls.

e.g.

```
<input id="Logueo" value="Login" class="btn btn-info btn-block" 
    onclick="javascript:validarLogueo() == 0 ? '@Url.Action('VistaViandasPersonal', 'Menu')' : '@Url.Action('VistaAdministrador', 'Menu')'">
```

I strongly recommend you move to using a jQuery event handler and never use inline handlers with jQuery. When you need a root site URL, that can be injected by your master page into a global variable

```
<script>
   window.siteRoot = "@Url.Content("~")";
</script>
```

and simply prepend this to any URLs in your jQuery code.

Comment: I'm trying it. I'll let you know.